# A first course in Complex Analysis with Applications

Tags: complex-numbers

Assume for the moment that $\sqrt{1+i}$. makes sense in the complex number system.

How would you then demonstrate the validity of the equality
$$\sqrt{1+i} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2}} + i\sqrt{-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2}}$$?

*Source*: *Dennis G. Zill* & *Patrick D. Shanahan*

I'm Confused that what to do to solve this one or what the question asks for?

Comment: Have you tried squaring the right-hand side?

Comment: @saulspatz not actually i didn't.

Comment: Try that.  If you have problems, update your question to reflect that.

Comment: @saulspatz i will

Comment: @saulspatz i did it but the result was 1+i without the square root, and it must be with square root

Comment: So the **square** of the right hand side is the same as the left hand side, but without the square root? Sounds pretty reasonable...........

Comment: @saulspatz i can square the left side too, and i will get an equall result, is that true ?

Comment: @user296602 yes but if i square the L.H.S they will be equall, is that true ?

Comment: It means that the thing on the right is *a* square root of $\sqrt{1 + i}$, but there are always two possible roots.

Comment: What is, by definition of square root, the relationship between $1+i$ and $\sqrt{1+i}$? Have you observed the same relationship between $1+i$ and that right-hand side expression? Does that make the equality plausible?

Comment: Sure, if you square the left hand side it will be $1+i.$  That's what square root means.  This is just a plausibility argument as Arthur points out.  Pretty soon you'll see the formal definitions.

Comment: @Arthur i know there is a relation but there is no equality for $1+i$ and \sqrt{1+i}

Comment: @saulspatz so i can square the both sides from the beginning and for the result i will get $1+i$ = $1+i$, but i think the result should be \sqrt{1+i} = \sqrt{1+i}..

Comment: How do you know $\sqrt{25}=5?$

Comment: I'm not saying that $1+i= \sqrt{1+i}$. That is not true, and it is not the relationship I mentioned in my above comment. The relationship between $1+i$ and $\sqrt{1+i}$ is a different one.

Comment: @Arthur yes, so what do u suggest !

Comment: @Arthur squaring both sides and get $1+i$ in both sides !

Comment: Exactly! And if two numbers have the same square, then they are likely to be equal (one could be the negative of the other, but that is all that could go wrong). That is as far as you can take this problem until you have a strict definition of square roots of complex numbers.

Comment: @Arthur Ok thats Fair for this que. Thanx for ur time.

Comment: @saulspatz thanx for help

Comment: You're most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to prove  o$$\sqrt{1+i} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2}} + i\sqrt{-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2}}$$

we square the right hand side and show that it is the same as $1+i.$

Note that $$\bigg (\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2}} + i\sqrt{-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2}}\bigg )^2 =$$

$$ \bigg( \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2}\bigg) -\bigg( \frac{-1}{2} +\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2}\bigg) + 2i  \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2}}    \sqrt{-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2}}=$$

$$ 1 +2i(1/2)=1+i$$

Comment: Yes i did it like that but i got $1+i$ just like u did, but is \sqrt{1+i} = $1+i$ ??

Comment: Remember we squered both side to get 1+i ? So it is OK.